# Astro Web Framework: getting "Unterminated regular expression" on importing Script inside astro file

Tags: javascript, astrojs

Error:

```
16:24:50 [watch] src/layouts/BaseLayout.astro
16:24:50 [ERROR] Unterminated regular expression
  Stack trace:
    at failureErrorWithLog (/Users/air/Documents/Projects/Astro/tutorial/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1651:15)
    [...] See full stack trace in the browser, or rerun with --verbose.
```

the problem seems to not be in the frontmatter as well as imported BaseLayout.

Index.astro that imports from layout file BaseLayout.astro

```
---
import BaseLayout from '../layouts/BaseLayout.astro';
const pageTitle = "Home Page";
---
<BaseLayout pageTitle={pageTitle}>
  <h2>My awesome blog subtitle</h2>
</BaseLayout>
```

BaseLayout.astro

```
---
import Header from '../components/Header.astro';
import Footer from '../components/Footer.astro';
import '../styles/global.css';
const { pageTitle } = Astro.props;
---
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator} />
    <title>{pageTitle}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <Header />
    <h1>{pageTitle}</h1>
    <slot />
    <Footer />
    <script>
      import "../scripts/menu.js";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: show your code where you call something defined in `esbuild/lib/main.js` It's probably a method call, something like that

Comment: not sure if this could be the reason, but you have some inconsistencies in your attributes, e.g. content="" and content={Astro.generator} (w/o the quotes). Try to wrap every such occurrence in quotes.